# How to call Bitrix24's API using Postman?

Tags: api, postman, bitrix

I researched on google and I'm stuck while I try to find out **Bitrix24** API docs for **users using PostMan**. Is there an available resource that could help me solve my trouble? , I hope I could retrieve a document or some things like this. Thanks for reading <3

Comment: https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/general/index.php. There's nothing specific to Postman. As long as you enter the REST API as defined in the bitrix24 docs, Postman will work just fine.

Comment: Mr.bitoiu I tried and it worked! Thanks for your recommend

Comment: Example for everyone who want to try: `https://{{your_bitrix_web_app}}/rest/crm.contact.list?auth={{your_access_token}}` it gets contact list. And you can follow [link](https://training.bitrix24.com/) to use other API REST

Answer (score 1):

Try this endpoint on your postman

https://example.bitrix24.id/rest/crm.product.list

This is for the CRM Product List
https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/crm/products/crm_product_list.php

if this dosent work you can put .json
https://example.bitrix24.id/rest/crm.product.list.json

for the authentication you can go to Developer Resources - Other - Local Application

and put Postman callback on the Handler (https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback).
dont forget to click the Script Only.